# Cached Dynamically loaded JS callback not working on 304

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

When using [$.getScrtip](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) it does not cache your dynamically loaded js, so i have this [custom one](http://themergency.com/an-alternative-to-jquerys-getscript-function/).

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    var load = true;
    //check all existing script tags in the page for the url
    jQuery('script[type="text/javascript"]')
      .each(function () {
          return load = (url != $(this).attr('src'));
      });
    console.log('load is ' + load);
    if (load) {
        //didn't find it in the page, so load it
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'script',
            cache: true,
            ifModified: true,
            success: callback

        });
    } else {
        //already loaded so just call the callback
        if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback.call(this);
        };
    };

};
```

it works on caching part, however it does not work when i am refreshing the page using f5 and 304 is received on next attempt to dynamically load js. i get function undefined for a function defined inside the loaded js. here is how i call this (this same code perfectly with $.getScript if replaced $.loadScript)

```
    function getvm() {
      return $.getScript("Scripts/ViewModel/cachedvm-1.0.0.js")
  }

  function functionthatinvokesjsload() {
      $.when($.get(myUrl), getvm())
          .done(function(a1, a2) {

              initializeVm();

          });
  }
```

**Error i am getting is initializeVm() is not defined when i get 304 on js load. it works the first time.** but if i later manually do it in browser debug window it does find that function. it seems to be i am trying to invoke the js before its loaded to DOM but not sure why that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

i had to use

```
jQuery.loadScriptNoCallBack = function (url) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        ifModified: true
    });
};
```